# How use arrays of double[4][4] contained in a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I want to ask at the community my problem.

I have a series of array of double[4][4] in this format:

```
double T1[4][4] = {
        {-0.9827,   -0.1811,   -0.0388,    0.1234},
        {0.0807,   -0.2303,   -0.9698,    0.1755},
        {0.1666,   -0.9561,    0.2409,    0.6729},
            {0,         0,         0,    1.00000    }};

double T2[4][4] = {
        {-0.8524,   -0.5029,   -0.1432,    0.1963},
        {0.1580,    0.0135,   -0.9874,    0.1285},
        {0.4984,   -0.8643,    0.0680,    0.6237}, 
            {0,         0,         0,    1.00000 }};
```

T3, T4, and so on....

I need to insert all of these arrays in a container, to pickup one at time from another function, that need arrays in that format, because doing these elaborations:

```
int verifica_punti(punto P, Mat& I, double TC[4][4], const double fc[2],const double KC[5], const double cc[2],const double alpha){

    //punto
    double P1[4] = {P.x, P.y, P.z, 1.0};

    //iniz
    double Pc[3] = {TC[0][3], TC[1][3], TC[2][3]};

    //calc
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            Pc[i] += TC[i][j] * P1[j];
        }
    }
        //norm
        double PN[2] = { Pc[0]/Pc[2], Pc[1]/Pc[2] };
```

Now, searching on this site and on internet I've found some examples to do this, but don't work in my case. Using vector, array, queue...I don't understand a thing.

I paste here my code, and tell you to help me fix this problem.

This is my code:

```
//array of TC

typedef array<array<double,4>,4> Matrix;

//single TC

Matrix T1 = {{
            {{-1.0000,   0.0000,  -0.0000,   0.1531}},
            {{0.0000,   0.0000,  -1.0000,   0.1502 }},
            {{-0.0000,  -1.0000,  -0.0000,   1.0790}},
            {{0 ,       0,        0,   1.0000     }}}}; 

Matrix T2 = {{  
            {{-1.0000,    0.0009,    0.0019,    0.1500}},
            {{-0.0021,   -0.4464,   -0.8948,    0.1845}},
            {{0.0000,   -0.8948,    0.4464,    0.8094 }},
            {{ 0,         0,         0,    1.0000    }}}};
```

etc....then, declare container and fill it:

```
vector <Matrix> TCS;

TCS.push_back(T1);
    TCS.push_back(T2);
    TCS.push_back(T3);
    TCS.push_back(T4);
    TCS.push_back(T5);
    TCS.push_back(T6);
    TCS.push_back(T7);
    TCS.push_back(T8);
    TCS.push_back(T9);
```

Now, for obtain single matrix in double[4][4] format to pass it at that function "verifica_punti" (written before) how can I do?

I need one TC at time, but in the FIFO order (the first that I've pushed, I need to pop and use.

How can I do this? Because I've write

```
 double  temp[4][4] = TCS.pop_back()
```

or   `double  temp[4][4] = TCS[i];`

but isn't correct.

I'm on Visual C++ 2010 on windows 7 64bit.

Help me please :-(  thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::vector::pop_back()` is a void function. It does not return anything. You may want to access the last `Matrix` with `std::vector::back()` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with

```
typedef array<array<double,4>,4> Matrix;
vector <Matrix> TCS;
```

You have

```
//double temp[4][4] = TCS[i]; // Illegal
Matrix m1 = TCS[i]; // legal
const Matrix& m2 = TCS[i]; // legal, and avoid a copy.
```

Now, you have to change:

```
int verifica_punti(punto P, Mat& I, double TC[][4], const double fc[], const double KC[], const double cc[], const double alpha);
```

to

```
int verifica_punti(punto P, Mat& I, Matrix& TC, const double fc[], const double KC[], const double cc[], const double alpha);
```

Comment: changing that in function "verifica_punto" affect the operations inside? Or I can change it without problem?

Comment: From what I see, you can change that without problem. At worst compiler would complain :)

Comment: Thank you very much...sorry, but I want to ask only other one thing: I need to push_back and "pop" from head, in this way, First element in, it's the first popped...how can I do this?

Comment: @AgentSmith891: You may look at FIFO queue adaptor : [std::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/).

Comment: Thank you very much, can I use queue instead of vector with my matrix type? Because I think that the syntax it's the same or not?

Comment: Yes, you can use `std::queue<Matrix>`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array< std::array<double,4>, 4>` and `double[4][4]` are distinct types. The former encupsulates the latter so that it's copyable and can be used in containers and it has practicaly identical interface. But you can't use them interchangeable.

You already have your typedef, so use that:

```
while (!TCS.empty()) {
    // get the last one
    Matrix m = TCS.back();

    /* do stuff with m */

    // pop the last one out
    TCS.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: using std::array< std::array<double,4>, 4> instead of classic, allowed the function to work with "m" like already do?

Comment: You'll need to change the function declaration to take `Matrix`, too.

Comment: Thank you very much...sorry, but I want to ask only other one thing: I need to push_back and "pop" from head, in this way, First element in, it's the first popped...how can I do this?

Comment: @AgentSmith891 Use `std::deque` or `std::queue` then.